# There is an error when click on bounties.

Tags: bug, status-completed, ux

[image]

Comment: step to reproduce. 1 : click on user profile , 2: then on the right middle tab click on bounties. 3: the above errors happen(Ooops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug in the initial deploy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95860/new-bounties-tab-in-profile-something-bad-happened) of this feature.

It has been fixed.

Comment: yes its now working.

Comment: but now propose wiki tag is not working.

Comment: @abdul - if that is the case then create a new question here about that issue.

Comment: but the system is not accepted another question. error message like " same question can not be posted."

Comment: @abdul - what are you trying to post? The same content you've posted here?

Comment: @charles not the same content, the post title is (Propose Edit Wiki Button is not working). but when i click on propose edit wiki, the button is not working.

Comment: its working now, i have post new question propose tag wiki not working.